# Trying to use Axios and Vue Bootstrap table to display data from API

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue

Hi everyone So I am having trouble displaying the data from this API to my Vue bootstrap table.

It is giving me this error:
**" Property or method "products" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.**"

The problem is in my App.vue I have products defined on the instance. So I don't understand why it is throwing me this error.

this is my App.vue

```
    <template>
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <PagTable :products="products"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios'
import PagTable from './components/PagTable.vue'

const vshredAPI = 'https://app.vshred.com/api/offers?include=images&per_page=25&page=1'

Vue.use(axios)
export default {
        name:"app",

        components: {
            PagTable
        },

        data(){
            return {
                Page:1,
                products: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchData()
        },
        
        methods: {
            fetchData () {
                axios.get(vshredAPI + this.page)
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        this.products= data
                    })
            }
        }
}
    

</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

PagTable component

```
  <template>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Image</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Purchase</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
        <th scope="row">1
                    {{ products.indexOf(product) + 1 }}
                </th>
        <td>{{product.id}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>
                    <img v-if="product.image.url" class="image" :src="product.image.url"/>
                </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'PageTable',

    props: {
        proudcuts: Array
    }
}

</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

if anyone could help me or guide me that would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo inside you PagTable component is written proudcuts, when it should be products, another thing is about your v-for it would be nice if you do it like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="product.id">
    <th scope="row">
      {{ index + 1 }}
    </th>
    <td>{{product.id}}</td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <img v-if="product.image.url" class="image" :src="product.image.url"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see you can get the index attribute from the v-for instead of using the products object, for more information check the docs in the link: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html